# How to navigate from a tableview inside another uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nested

In my ios application,There is a tableview inside another tableviewCell.It may be a bad idea to have nested tableviews.But I need it this way.I have the datasource methods of inner tableView inside the cell of outer tableview.It is working well.

***My problem is :
We cannot do "performSegue" from tableviewCell.m file.***

> I tried setting the outer TableViewController as the delegate of inner
>   tableview.it works great.But I have to pass some data from
>   innnerTableview to outer tableview.I tried this by creating a protocol
>   inside innertableviewcell.This is not working.

***HOW TO PASS DATA FROM INNER_TABLEVIEW TO MAIN-TABLEVIEW?***

Comment: Have you tried having a reference of your main table view inside your inner table view ? If you put a delegate you'd be able to call a method from your inner table view tower you

Answer (score 3):

You have like 3 ways to structure your data flow between your objects. The first one is the delegation. This is my favourite cup of tea. Set up a protocol inside the inner TableView and make the outer confirm on it.

And you can also make use of notification. Send a notification and observe it in your outer table view.

The 3 way is to have a reference to the outer table in the inner table.